# Including Google Analytics wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I know there are many different ways you can include the Google Analytics script into a Wordpress website, but I won't use plugins for this.

So the way I would like to prefer is to code it into the theme's functions file, giving me two options left. (yes it's a child theme)

- creating a function with analytics script inside, linking this to header/footer
- using the default way Wordpress asks to enqueue scripts at `wp_enqueue_scripts`

The outcome of the above ways will be different so with my little Wordpress experience, I was wondering what should be the **safest** and most **secure** way to embed it into a Wordpress site? Eventually I might consider also the difference in loading time, also the **fastest** way?

Answer (score 2):

`wp_enqueue_script` with parameter `$in_footer` set to `false`, is the same as hardcoding the script into the html head (in fact, it would be included in the place where `wp_head()` is called, which should be inside the `<head></head>` tags).

`wp_enqueue_script` gives you the ability to add a dependency to the script you are adding, but for google analytics you don't need any, so from safety and security you are covered. From speed's point of view, I guess hardcoding it would be very slightly faster, but your header will look bigger, so it's up to you to trade readability and enqueue it or just add it as a script. The header usually is not a large file anyway, so most of the times I just copy-paste the code inside the head as it is.

Answer (score 2):

This code adds Analytics and excludes the traffic of connected users (useful to avoid registering your visits).

```
<?php
   if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
      function addAnalytics() {
         $analyticsTag = "<!-- Google Analytics -->
                          <script> Codice di traccimento </script>
                          <!-- Google Analytics -->";
         echo $analyticsTag;
      }
      add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addAnalytics');
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created a child theme just copy over the header file and add your google analytics code before the closing  tag. That is an easy option and that is what I always do for my WP sites.

Answer (score 0):

`Google Analytics` tracking code is asynchronous. It doesn't need to wait for the code to finish loading to continue rendering elements that come after it on the page. It's a good idea to get into the habit of placing the `GTM container snippet` in the head section because that's where asynchronously loading libraries should be placed.